# Css: how to combine table and column specification into a single selector?

Tags: css

I have a table which I've given class `class1`. I'd like to write css to set the border for it and it's columns. I did so below, but is there a way to rewrite to combine this into a single selector?

```
.class1 {
    border: 1px solid black;
     border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.class1 td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Please select the best answer. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

- by combining selectors

  ```css
  table.class1,
  table.class1 td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <table class="class1">
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  ```

**OR**

- by adding `class1` to the table cells along with the table.

  ```css
  .class1 {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <table class="class1">
    <tr>
      <td class="class1">Jill</td>
      <td class="class1">Smith</td> 
      <td class="class1">50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="class1">Eve</td>
      <td class="class1">Jackson</td> 
      <td class="class1">94</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  ```

***The second one will increase your code size significantly and also requires more effort, it is a dirty hack to use only one "atomic" selector. The LOCs saved in the CSS are not worth the work in the HTML*** But this is probably what you want, sorry no other better (efficient) way to do it.

***I would go with the first one, even though it is a combination of selectors.***

Comment: I would add that the first option is normally preferable, since the HTML is more clean and maintainable. Btw the second is a good point because the question asks about a "single selector".

Comment: I have some-what mentioned that at the end of my answer, however I should make it more clear; editing now.

Answer (score 1):

If you want identical result compared to your sample CSS, the suggestions the others made will not work. This was your

### original CSS:

```
.class1 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.class1 td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

The

### others suggested

```
.class1, table.class1 td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

but this is not the same as your rules.

### It is identical to

```
.class1 {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.class1 td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

which is **not** the css you gave us to shorten.

In case you want your property declarations to not be redundantly defined, you

### go like this:

```
.class1, 
table.class1 td {
    /* all properties both elements have in common */        
    border: 1px solid black; 
}
.class1 {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

*Please note that although `border-collapse` will be ignored for `td` this is simply coincidence as the OP could also have asked for completely different elements and styles.*

Answer (score 0):

You can combine your two selectors into one, and the border-collapse will be ignored on the table cells, but the border will be applied:

```
.class1, table.class1 td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write:

```
table.class1,
table.class1 td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Of course `border-collapse: collapse;` will be ignored for `td`, but it will still apply to the `table`.

**Ref**: See [5.2.1 Grouping Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#grouping)